# What is the RPM equivalent to `dpkg --compare-versions ...`?

Tags: debian, fedora, rpm, dpkg, version

Debian offers a way to compare Debian compatible versions using the `dpkg` command like so:

```
dpkg --compare-versions <version> <operator> <version>
```

For example, if you want to know whether a given version is before 1.0, then you can use:

```
# gather VERSION from somewhere...
VERSION=0.9

if dpkg --compare-versions "${VERSION}" lt 1.0
then
    echo "unacceptable version as per policy"
    exit 1
fi
```

What is the equivalent command under an RPM-based (RedHat/Fedora) system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpmdev-vercmp` from `rpmdevtools` package provides similar functionality, but doesn't support specifying the operator, it simply returns 0 if the versions are equal, 11 if version1 is newer, and 12 if version2 is newer.

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp 1.12 1.13
1.12 < 1.13
$ echo $?
12
```

You can also install dpkg in Fedora, [it is available in the default repository](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/dpkg/dpkg/). But it might be a little too much to install dpkg just for the version comparison.

Comment: I was looking for a tool that verifies RPM versions to make sure that my own sort code works as expected (so I can test my code against an official tool). So `dpkg` is not useful in my situation.

Comment: Hmmm... that tool does not seem to detect invalid characters in versions. At least [the docs](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/spec.html#version) say we should not be able to use characters such as `#` and yet the tool runs just fine with `rpmdev-vercmp 1#3 1#4`.

Comment: It's unfortunately just a simple Python script that doesn't do any checks for valid input: https://github.com/rsrchboy/rpmdevtools/blob/master/rpmdev-vercmp

Answer (score 5):

On [rpm >= 4.16.0](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/lua):

```
$ rpm --eval "%{lua:print(rpm.vercmp('1.2-1', '2.0-1'))}"
-1
```

([rpm >= 4.7.0 compares only parts](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/897), not full Epoch:Version-Release strings)

For OpenSUSE, there is also `zypper vcmp`:

```
$ zypper vcmp 0.9.5+git20190908+3abfab2-150300.7.5.1 0.9.5~git20210406.e554475-150400.3.5.1
0.9.5+git20190908+3abfab2-150300.7.5.1 is newer than 0.9.5~git20210406.e554475-150400.3.5.1
```

Comment: Interesting... so rpm decided to use Lua just like Debian uses Python?